# Knockout update observable

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, observable

I am extending application with knockout.js set up where I want to dynamically display file upload. This is my code

```
function Search() {
    var self = this; 
    //many different items set

    self.totalSize = ko.observable(total);
    self.uploadedSize = ko.observable(uploaded);
}

var uploadProgress;

var total = 100;
var uploaded = 0;

function runUploadProgress() {
    uploadProgress = setInterval(function () {
        callWebApi({
            api: webapi.getUploadProgress,
            data: null,
            cache: false,
            success: function (json) {
                total = json.TotalBytes;
                uploaded = json.TransferedBytes;
                console.log(total + " - " + uploaded);
            }
        });
        if (total == uploaded) {
            stopUploadProgress();
        }
    }, 1000);
    return true;
}

function stopUploadProgress() {
    clearInterval(uploadProgress);
}
```

How can I make the totalSize and uploadedSize observable update with new values? Thought if I change the value of total and uploaded it would change the value in observables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After creating the observable you have to change the observable value with

```
searchInstance.totalSize(json.TotalBytes);
searchInstance.uploadedSzie(json.TransferedBytes);
```

Comment: Indeed.  @Bartosz - note that only the _values_ of `total` and `uploaded` are used to initialise the observables - the knockout observables are completely unaware of the variables themselves and have no reference to them.